# Writing a file and Reading it in Perl

Tags: perl

I'm trying to build a primary key into a new file from an original File which has the following structure (**tbl_20180615.txt**):

```
573103150033,0664,54,MSS02VEN*',INT,zxzc,,,,,
573103150033,0665,54,MSS02VEN,INT,zxzc,,,,,
573103150080,0659,29,MSS05ARA',INT,zxzc,,,,,
573103150080,0660,29,MSS05ARA ,INT,zxzc,,,,,
573103154377,1240,72,MSSTRI01,INT,zxzc,,,,,
573103154377,1240,72,MSSTRI01,INT,zxzc,,,,,
```

I launch my `perl Verify.pl` then I send the arguments, the first one is the number of columns to build the primary key in the new file, after I have to send the name of file (original file).

(**Verify.pl**)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $n1   = $ARGV[0];
my $name = $ARGV[1];

$n1 =~ s/"//g;
my $n2 = $n1 + 1;

my %seen;

my ( $file3 ) = qw(log.txt);
open my $fh3, '>', $file3 or die "Can't open $file3: $!";

print "Loading file ...\n";
open( my $file, "<", "$name" ) || die "Can't read file somefile.txt: $!";

while ( <$file> ) {

    chomp;
    my @rec = split( /,/, $_, $n2 );    #$n2 sirve para armar la primary key, hacer le split en los campos deseados

    for ( my $i = 0; $i < $n1; $i++ ) {
        print $fh3 "@rec[$i],";
    }

    print $fh3 "\n";
}

close( $file );

print "Done!\n";
```

#########to check duplicates

```
my ($file4) = qw(log.txt);

print "Checking duplicates records...\n\n";

open (my $file4, "<", "log.txt") || die "Can't read file log.txt: $!";

while ( <$file4> ) { 
    print if $seen{$_}++;
}

close($file4);
```

if I send the following instruction

```
perl Verify.pl 2 tbl_20180615.txt
```

this code build a new file called "log.txt" with the following structure, splitting the original file () into two columns given by the first argument:
(**log.txt**)

```
573103150033,0664,
573103150033,0665,
573103150080,0659,
573103150080,0660,
573103154377,1240,
573103154377,1240,
```

That works ok, but if I want to read the new file `log.txt` to check duplicates, it doesn't work, but If I comment the lines to generate the file `log.txt` (listed above) before the line in the code (###############to check duplicates################) launch the next part of the code it works ok, giving me two duplicates lines and looks like this:
(**Result in command line**)

```
573103154377,1240
573103154377,1240
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: I've cleaned up your question a little bit to make it look nicer. I think there are now too many empty lines in the output. Please [edit] the question and clean it up. Please also show us what the expected output is. What do you want the new file to look like when it's working. Please see [mcve].

Comment: I expect to get the following >>Checking duplicates records...
573103154377,1240 and 573103154377,1240, running whole code which are two dupicate lines

Comment: Are there really so many blank lines in the input and output?

Comment: Actually, there are not blank lines. I put there to beautifier the view in here...

Comment: @Richard: It's important that you post accurate data, especially the tabs, spaces, newlines which are otherwise invisible. The presence of blank lines makes a big difference to the content of the code. There are also a lot of files here and it's far from clear which is which. Please can you label which contents belong to `log.txt`, `Verify.pl`, and `tbl_20180615.txt` and explain the other file contents that you show?

Answer (score 0):

I think this does what you're asking for. It builds a unique list of derived keys before printing any of them, using a hash to check whether a key has already been generated

Note that I have assigned values to `@ARGV` to emulate input values. You must remove that statement before running the program with input from the command line

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;  # Handle bad IO statuses automatically

local @ARGV = qw/ 2 tbl_20180615.txt /; # For testing only

tr/"//d for @ARGV;  # "

my ($key_fields, $input_file) = @ARGV;
my $output_file = 'log.txt';

my (@keys, %seen);

print "Loading input ... ";
open my $in_fh, '<', $input_file;

while ( <$in_fh> ) {

    chomp;
    my @rec = split /,/;

    my $key = join ',', @rec[0..$key_fields-1];

    push @keys, $key unless $seen{$key}++;
}

print "Done\n";

open my $out_fh, '>', $output_file;
print $out_fh "$_\n" for @keys;
close $out_fh;
```

#### output `log.txt`

```
573103150033,0664
573103150033,0665
573103150080,0659
573103150080,0660
573103154377,1240
```

Comment: It looks nice. However,  I need to show duplicates records just in case if there are...

Comment: I have to build a file, just like you did but keeping in mind all records, after that I need to do other operation where one of them is check duplicates records which I'm attempting and fail in this operation. I have my file called log.txt, which is almost the same the first one. So I need to chechk duplicates records and show them. Regards

Comment: @Richard: I'm sorry, but if you can't use my answer to fulfil your complete requirements then you need to ask another question. I've written code that solves what I understood your problem to be. If you need more then you must be much more careful about specifying your requirement *precisely*. What experience do you have in programming with Perl, or with any language?

Comment: Actually you never answered my question, but it helps me to see in a different way the code. I appreciate it. On the other hand, it was my first code on Perl. I have kind of experience in Shell script...

Comment: @Richard: Your question is *"How can I solve this issue?"* and I provided  a solution. How is that not answering your question?